# SQL Error: ORA-00955

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I cant create this table. 
It says that the columns names  are already used by another object ???

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: end your statements with a ;

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-00955

The error means that you have an object in your database with the same name that of your table.

- Either use a different name for your new table
- Drop the existing object with same name if you do not need it.

To check the existing object, you could query **[ALL|USER|DBA]_OBJECTS** view:

```
SELECT object_name, object_type FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'DEPT_X1';;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your column name, but with the name of your table. There is already a table named `DEPT_X1` in your database, perhaps because you've executed this command more than once. To verify this execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'DEPT_X1';
```

If this query returns data it means that there is already something named `DEPT_X1` in your database. To find out what it is look at the `OBJECT_TYPE` column in the data returned by the query above. If `OBJECT_TYPE` = `'TABLE'` it means that the existing `DEPT_X1` is a table; if `OBJECT_TYPE` = `'SEQUENCE'` it means `DEPT_X1` is a sequence; etc. Let's say for the sake of argument that the existing `DEPT_X1` is a table and that you want to get rid of the one that's already there so you can create another. You'd want to use a `DROP TABLE` command similar to the following:

```
DROP TABLE DEPT_X1;
```

After running the above successfully you could then re-create the table using your existing script. If the existing `DEPT_X1` is some other kind of database object you'd have to use the correct `DROP` command for that particular kind of object - there are many different `DROP` commands [which are documented here (see chapters 17 and 18)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm).

Best of luck.